# How to use output clause in SQL to output insert, update, delete results into new temporary table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, output-clause

Currently, I'm trying to perform an `update` in SQL Server (but it could be any [DML statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) that supports the [`output` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)), and I'd like to put the output into a local temp table, like so:

```
update
    dbo.MyTable
set
    MyField = 30
output
    inserted.MyKeyField
into
    #myTempTable
from
    dbo.MyTable as t
where
    f.MyFilteredField = 8
```

I know the syntax is correct, as per the documentation for the `output` clause (emphasis mine):

> output_table
>
> Specifies a table that the returned rows are inserted into instead of
>   being returned to the caller. **output_table may be a temporary table**.

That said, I'd expect it to work just like it would on the the [`into` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) on a `select` statement in that it would just create the table.

However, I get the following error:

> Invalid object name '#myTempTable'.

How can I get the results of the `output` clause (`inserted` or `deleted`) into a temp table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `output` clause will not generate a new table, so you have to [generate the table beforehand which matches the structure of what is specified in the `output` clause](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/output-clause.aspx), for example:

```
select t.MyKeyField into #myTempTable from dbo.MyTable as t where 1 = 0
```

Note, you don't have to use the `select into` syntax above, [`create table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) works just as well.  In the end, whatever is easiest to create an empty temporary table that matches the fields in your `output` clause.

Once the table is created, the "Invalid object name" error will go away and the DML statement will execute without error (assuming there are no other errors).

Comment: It's unfortunate that this is the case, since it means picking between losing the convenience of temp table type detection, or significant code duplication.